# Kivy Popup Dynamic Height

Tags: python, kivy

I'm looking to make a popup on the python-side that has a dynamic height.

So far, I have this within the screens `__init__` class. The kv file has another widget that called the popup on_release. Anyways, I have found that this produces a popup with very wonky formatting:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

kv = '''

ScreenManagement:
    id: 'manager'
    BrokenPopup:
        name: 'broken'
        manager: 'manager'

<BrokenPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Test'
            on_release: root.p.open()

'''

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BrokenPopup(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BrokenPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.p = Popup(auto_dismiss=False, size_hint_x=.6, size_hint_y=None, title='A popup')
        self.g = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10)
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Test1', size_hint_y=None, height=32))
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Test2', size_hint_y=None, height=32))
        self.g.bind(minimum_height=self.g.setter('height'))
        self.p.add_widget(self.g)
        self.p.bind(height=self.g.setter('height')) #<- this does not work to change the popup height!

class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TheApp().run()
```

The popup size is set to fit only one widget, leaving the second button (and all others that may be included) to float beyond the confines of the popup border.

How should I change the code so that all of the widgets fit within the confines of the popup? I am trying to do that by dynamically setting the height of the popup, however that is not proving effective.

Comment: Not sure what "does not work" means, please be more specific. But one thing I see is that `self.p` can only refer to one `Popup` at a time,  so how do you currently try to create a second `Popup`. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I have updated the question to be more specific. Essentially, the widgets float beyond the borders of the popup. I want to set the height of the popup so that it fits the widgets within it, and I want to do this dynamically in case other widgets are added to the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my original problem that is influenced by John Anderson's answer. I'll provide a walkthrough below for how I came to this solution.

1) Here's a photo of my original problem; I needed to dynamically set the popup height based on the widgets that are assigned to it. Before finding the below solution, my popup looked like this with the code in the OP:

[image: Original popup with a height error.]

As you can see, the widgets go beyond the borders of the popup.

2) I found something interesting while looking inside the popup widget with the inspector tool.

```
python '/path/to/your/file.py' -m inspector
```

Using control-e, I can click widgets and inspect their attributes. I clicked the popup button and cycled through the parent widgets until I found the popup widget.

[image]

As you can see in the photo, the popup widget has one child: a grid layout. Here are the children of that grid layout:

[image]

Interestingly, the grid layout contains:

- One label, with a height of 33
- One line, with a height of 4
- A box layout, which contains the contents of the popup
- 2 units of spacing between these three widgets
- 12 units of padding all-around; so 24 additional units to consider for the height

3) In my solution, I have hard-written the default heights of the label, the line widget, and all default popup spacing and padding. Then, I cycle through the children inside the box layout, and add their heights. I also add 10 to those children heights, as the gridlayout that contains all of these widgets uses a spacing of 10.

---

**Solution:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

kv = '''

ScreenManagement:
    id: 'manager'
    BrokenPopup:
        name: 'broken'
        manager: 'manager'

<BrokenPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Test'
            on_release: root.p.open()

'''

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BrokenPopup(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BrokenPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.p = Popup(auto_dismiss=False, size_hint_x=.6, size_hint_y=None, title='A popup')
        self.g = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, padding=[0,10,0,-5])
        self.g.bind(minimum_height=self.fix_popup_height) # <- here's the magic
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Test1', size_hint_y=None, height=32))
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Test2', size_hint_y=None, height=32))
        self.p.add_widget(self.g)


    def fix_popup_height(self, grid, *args):
        # a generalized function that, when bound to minimum_height for a grid with popup widgets,
        # this will set the height of the popup
        height = 0
        height += 33    # for popup label
        height += 4     # for popup line widget
        height += 24    # for popup padding
        height += 2     # for spacing between main popup widgets
        for child in grid.children:
            height += child.height + 10 # adds 10 for the spacing between each child
        grid.parent.parent.parent.height = height # sets popup height
        pass


class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TheApp().run()
```

Notable changes from the OP:

- Bind the `minimum_height` of the widget container to the `fix_popup_height()` function; this will trigger each time a widget is added to the popup.
- Declare the `fix_popup_height()` within the screen class.

Here's the fixed popup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to do what I think you want. Basically it adds the `minimum_height` from the `GridLayout`, that is added to your `Popup`, to the calculated height of the `title` and the dividing bar. The first `Button` in the `GridLayout` now adds another `Button` to the `GridLayout` for testing.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

kv = '''

ScreenManagement:
    id: 'manager'
    BrokenPopup:
        name: 'broken'
        manager: 'manager'

<BrokenPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Test'
            on_release: root.p.open()

'''


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BrokenPopup(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BrokenPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.popup_title_height = None
        self.p = Popup(auto_dismiss=False, size_hint_x=.6, size_hint_y=None, title='A popup')
        self.g = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10)
        self.g.bind(minimum_height=self.fix_size)
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Test1', size_hint_y=None, height=32, on_release=self.add_one))
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Test2', size_hint_y=None, height=32))
        self.p.add_widget(self.g)


    def add_one(self, *args):
        self.g.add_widget(Button(text='Another', size_hint_y=None, height=32))


    def get_popup_title_height(self):
        height = 0
        popupGrid = self.p.children[0]
        height += popupGrid.padding[1] + popupGrid.padding[3]
        for child in popupGrid.children:
            if isinstance(child, BoxLayout):
                continue
            else:
                height += child.height + popupGrid.spacing[1]
        self.popup_title_height = height


    def fix_size(self, *args):
        if self.popup_title_height is None:
            self.get_popup_title_height()
        self.p.height = self.g.minimum_height + self.popup_title_height


class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TheApp().run()
```

I cheated a bit by looking at the code for `Popup` and the `style.kv` file to see how the `Popup` is displayed. So, if any of that is changed, this may not work.

Comment: I was looking at the popup through the inspector and also noticed that it has three children (the popup label, a widget for the line, and then a box layout that contains its content). I figured that the solution would require cycling through those children and adding their height, so this makes sense as a solution. For me, I will likely combine `fix_size()` and `get_popup_title_height()` for my code. Thanks for the hand!